# I installed Active Directory on Windows 2008 R2, and now I can't log in

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

After installing the Directory Services Role and running dcpromo to configure a new forest and controller, the wizard advises me to reboot.  After doing so, I can no longer log in to the server as before (via RDP).  What happened?  This is a virtual server with nothing else on it, so destroying it and starting over is an option, but how do I avoid this problem in the first place?

[image]

Comment: What error presents itself when you try to log in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't log into the server anymore because domain controllers do not have local user accounts. The local user accounts were converted to domain builtin accounts during the DCPROMO process. You need to log on to the domain from the server in the form of:

domain\username

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks.  I should'a thought of that.

Comment: Glad to help...